# Angular sort array of dicts by enum values in that dict

Tags: javascript, angular, sorting, dictionary, enums

I have some data that I am calling from a http service. This data contains month-names, those are defined as enum objects in natural calender order... I now have an array, where I push the Month names with some additional integers together in a dict. e.g:

```
[{name:Februar, value: 999},{name: Januar, value: 123}, {name: Oktober, value: 321},...]
```

Then I push the dict into the array. Now, I would like to sort the array afterwards by the dictionary enum entries... so January comes first, then February... etc.:

```
[{name: Januar, value: 123},{name:Februar, value: 999}, {name: Oktober, value: 321},...]
```

My code looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {Http,Response} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgxChartsModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-charts';

@Component({
  selector: 'productsbydemomonth',
  templateUrl: './productsbydemomonth.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./productsbydemomonth.component.scss']
})
export class ProductsbydemomonthComponent implements OnInit {

  dataArray : any[];
  Anzahl: number[] = [];
  Monat: Monat;
  chartData: any = [];

  view: any[] = [700, 400];

  // options
  showXAxis = true;
  showYAxis = true;
  gradient = false;
  showLegend = true;
  showXAxisLabel = true;
  xAxisLabel = 'Monat';
  showYAxisLabel = true;
  yAxisLabel = 'Anzahl';


  monatConst: number = 12;

  colorScheme = {
    domain: ['#5AA454', '#A10A28', '#C7B42C', '#AAAAAA']
  };
  monthArray: Monat[] = [Monat.Januar, Monat.Februar, Monat.Maerz, Monat.April, Monat.Mai, Monat.Juni, Monat.Juli, Monat.August, Monat.September, Monat.Oktober, Monat.November,Monat.Dezember ]

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    //this.getChartsData();
  }

  getChartsData() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:5555/DNZ/Produkt/Monat/by/' + (this.monatConst))
    .subscribe((res: Response) => {
      this.chartData = res.json() ;
      this.dataArray = this.formatData(this.chartData);       
    },
    (err) => {
      if (err.error instanceof Error) {
        console.log('Client-side error occured.');
      } else {
        console.log('Server-side error occured.');
      }
    });
  }

  formatData(someData) {
    this.dataArray = [];

    for (let dat of someData) {
      var dictChart = {
        name: dat.Monat,
        value: dat.Anzahl,      
      };
      //console.log(dictChart);
      this.dataArray.push(dictChart);
    }
    //console.log("Im Array:", this.dataArray);
    this.dataArray.sort(name);
    return this.dataArray;
  }

}


interface chartData {
  Anzahl : number,
  DemoID : number,
  Monat: Monat
}

enum Monat {"Januar","Februar","Maerz","April","Mai","Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"}
```

How can I sort those data in the array of dicts by their month names? So that they are displayed in the chart in the correct month name order on the x-axis? (don't bother about the chart, it just displays the array order...)

Answer (score 0):

### Mapping Months to values for sorting

What you want to do is use `.sort`, but sort uses values to sort up and down, therefore, you have to map each month to a value like below:

```js
const months = {
 January: 0,
 February: 1,
 March: 2,
 April: 3
}

let yourObject = [{month:'April'},{month:'January'},{month:'March'}]

console.log(yourObject.sort((data, prev) => months[data.month] - months[prev.month]))
```

`.sort((data, prev) => months[data.month] - months[prev.month])`

Answer (score 0):

`sort` method requires a comparator function as a parameter, e.g.:

```
const monthNum = month => this.monthArray.indexOf(month);
dataArray.sort((a, b) => monthNum(a) - monthNum(b))
```

Basically the function takes two arguments and should return some value that is either less than 0, equal 0 or greater than 0 (btw. `true` and `false` equal 1 and 0 respectively, so it may in fact return boolean value too).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

```
arr.sort((data, prev) => {
    return this.monthArray.indexOf(data.name) - this.monthArray.indexOf(prev.name);
})
```